# Unable to transmit as an iBeacon from iPad Air

Tags: ios, ipad, ibeacon

We have an existing iPad app that we are adding iBeacon transmitting capabilities to. I am unable to transmit an iBeacon signal. I won't provide the code at this point because I've also tested the Apple AirLocate example and the Radius Networks Locate iB app as a transmitter and in both cases the iPad won't transmit a beacon.

We tested with iPhone 5 devices and they can both transmit and range beacons.

What could be the issue with our iPad test device that it won't transmit? It can range beacons from the iPhones just fine.

BT is enabled. Location Services are enabled and approved for the apps in question.

Comment: Try reboot. I had an issue with iBeacons. My app couldn't detect anymore iBeacon (neither "real" ones, or iDevices ones) on both iDevices (my iPhone 4S & an iPhone 5S). A reboot made the detection work again. I guess that was an issue with iOS7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two likely causes:

1. The Proximity UUID of the iBeacon transmitter is not configured with Locate for iBeacon or Air Locate.  Locate cannot see new iBeacons with unknown Proximity UUIDs.  Even if the configuration is off by only a single digit, the iBeacon will be invisible.
2. Many users have reported recently that their phones are getting into a state where they cannot see iBeacons, and a reboot solves the problem.  [See here for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22949187/1461050)

Comment: David got this one! Thanks for all the back and forth help here and in email, David. I kept thinking the iPad was the problem, but it was the iPhone which was messed up. It could transmit but not receive and I thought it was the transmitting iPad that was the issue. A hard reboot of the iPhone cleared it all up.

Answer (score 0):

How do you detect the iBeacon, actually?

I once encountered the problem that `CLLocationManager#startMonitoringForRegion:` did require a certain period of time, until the regions were updated and a region was ranged. So `CLLocationManager#requestStateForRegion:`...

In either way. What I first did to validate that beacons were emitting/sending correctly (not receiving): I downloaded a common Bluetooth Scanning-App and checked, whether the App is able to range the emitted beacon. Could you verify this at first? Maybe the iPad Air is sending correctly, but the receives do not range the beacon yet.