# Gimbal S10 in iBeacon Mode is not showing in Apple's Sample AirLocate App

Tags: ios, core-location, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, gimbal

I am using a Gimbal series 10 device configured in iBeacon mode using one of the AirLocate UUIDs (the first one - E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0).  When I use iBeacon Locate on my Android phone, I can see the Gimbal broadcasting the correct UUID.  However, when I try to use Apple's `AirLocate` demo app, it is not working in trying to find the iBeacon.  I also cannot find it in the iOS version of iBeacon Locate, by the same company, Radius Networks.

I am using the beta version of Xcode / iOS.

We have internal apps that would like to use the micro-location features that iBeacons allow, and I'm trying to put together a quick proof of concept.  Unless I can get the iBeacon distance using the sample code in AirLocate, I cannot proceed.  Any help or experience with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The distance is not very precise anyways.. +-5meters

Comment: I know gimbals work fine with iOS as we use two different gimbal models and both work - so do estimates

Comment: The do.  See my comment below for the reason why it wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

**First**, Look closely to verify that have every single character of that ProximityUUID entered as above in the Gimbal configuration.  If even one character is off, it will not be visible in AirLocate or the iOS version of the [Locate for iBeacon app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconlocate).

The Android version of [iBeacon Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconlocate) shows all iBeacons regardless of ProximityUUID, so it will still be visible in the event of a configuration issue.

**Second**, there is a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22949187/1461050) in iOS 7.1 `CoreLocation` where iBeacon detections can stop entirely until you reboot your phone.  Try rebooting and see if the beacon starts showing up in both applications on iOS.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses.  It turns out that it was due to me using a beta version of Xcode to compile the AirLocate app and push to the device.  I don't know if the problem is with the new Base SDK, or with Xcode (my bet is on the SDK).  As I can't really comment on Apple beta stuff, I'll have to leave it at that.  

I'll have to look into the 7.1 bug as well, since that may cause us some problems in what we want to use this for.  Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Looks like it was a combination of my answer and yours.  I rebooted my phone and the Locate for iBeacon app is now also seeing the iBeacons.  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: BTW, I will upvote this once I get enough of a reputation to do so.  Working on it.

Comment: Ha!  Thanks.  I didn't even know you needed a certain reputation to upvote!