# ibeacon on ios 7.1 - app stop listening to beacon after a while

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I m building some app with iBeacon capability. The app will given notification when enter beacon region.

However, the app somehow stops listening to beacon after a few hours to half day. I does not start listening either after I kill the app and start it again. It only works after I restart the phone.

Ps: I m running ios 7.1.1 on a 4s.

Also, it has been mention by a few online post that app can listen to beacon region even if the app is not running at the background. That's has never worked for me.

I need a few pointers from someone who has successfully made this happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing a known iOS 7.1 bug that makes CoreLocation stop looking for iBeacons after awhile.  See here: [iBeacon: didRangeBeacons stops getting called, must reset device for it to work again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946022/ibeacon-didrangebeacons-stops-getting-called-must-reset-device-for-it-to-work)

There is no known solution.  You simply have to reboot your phone as a workaround until Apple releases iOS 7.2 with (hopefully) a fix.

To test background monitoring with the app not running, simply do a first detection with your app, reboot your phone, and wait up to 15 min while your iBeacon is transmitting.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed fits my observation. This bug pretty much made ibeacon experience for any app. And making users restarting their device is an unacceptably work around! Have you tried ios 8 beta? Is it fixed?

Comment: I have not tested iOS 8 beta yet, but would be curious to hear if it is fixed.  (Although the Apple NDA technically prohibits any beta users from discussing if it is fixed.)

Comment: All right then, my guess is that it works - and I hereby decline to comment on whether this speculation is based on actual testing or not.

Comment: Hi, is iOS 7.1.2 also affected by this bug?